# User locking postgres/postigs table without privileges

Tags: postgis, postgresql, administration, cadcorp-sis

I have a PostgreSQL 8.4.4 database with PostGIS 1.4.2 and I am experiencing a problem where an external GIS system (using embedded CadCorp SIS 7.0) is connecting to the database and taking Access Share Locks on a large number of tables which, as far as I can understand, it should not have privileges to access. The affected tables are all sources for views that are registered in geometry_columns, across a number of schemas. All other tables, whether registered in geometry_columns or not, with or without a geometry column, are unaffected (except those explicitly required by the map project the external system is using). This is frustrating because the connections stay open for a large period of time and prevent a lot of maintenance work that I might like to do.

For example I have a schema:

```
CREATE SCHEMA my_schema AUTHORIZATION user_one;  
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA my_schema TO user_one;
```

And within that a table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_schema.my_table...;  
ALTER TABLE my_schema.my_table OWNER TO user_one;  
GRANT ALL ON TABLE my_schema.my_table TO user_one;
```

And a view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_schema.vw_my_view AS SELECT... FROM my_schema.my_table;  
ALTER TABLE my_schema.vw_my_view OWNER TO superuser;  
GRANT ALL ON TABLE my_schema.vw_my_view TO superuser;  
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE my_schema.vw_my_view TO user_one;
```

The roles user_one and user_two are independent but I find that user_two is able to put an Access Share Lock on my_schema.my_table. If I connect to the database as user_two I am denied access to my_schema.my_table as I would expect.

Is there something I'm not doing with the privileges or roles that would prevent this? Why is it only those tables that are the source for views that are registered in geometry_columns that are affected?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Database Administration, which is a better fit for dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: It is do with administration but as it seems to specifically involve interactions with geometry_columns and only affects tables referenced by spatial views I thought it had a better fit with the GIS community.

Comment: You can restrict by IP on the POSTGRES side - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html or make the the tables readyonly (or using a view mode). http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-createview.html

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe I had a job that was specify called 'GIS Administrator' this included all Spatial Database setup, Maintenance, Backup, Licensing, Training knowledge etc)

Comment: @Mapperz - I do need user_two to access the database so their IP must be allowed to connect; I would like to deny user_two access to particular tables to stop it acquiring locks on them, but, as I understand the above privileges, user_two has not been given access in the first place, either to see the schema, the table, or the view.

Comment: superuser can remove/grant privileges http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/app-createuser.html CADcorp must be connecting as an user. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464623/how-can-you-get-the-active-users-connected-to-a-postgresql-database-via-sql

Comment: @Mapperz - CadCorp is connecting as user_two in my example. If user_one is the owner and PUBLIC has not been granted access how is user_two circumventing the privileges to acquire a lock on the table?

Comment: @Mapperz: I just feel that for these kinds of questions, sometimes the perspective of a DBA gives better insight that that of a person who approaches it from the GIS end.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe - I will give this question an airing on dba.stackexchange as well. I thought another GIS user might have come across it as it seems to be linked so closely to the geometry_columns table.

Comment: The DBA Stack Exchange question is [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58957/user-locking-tables-without-privileges).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was fixed in SIS 7.1 two years ago, but apparently not merged into 7.0. If you can email more details to me (martin dot daly at cadcorp dot com) then I'm sure that we can sort something out.

Please include the details of the application that embeds SIS, in case the supplier needs to be involved too.

Comment: I will contact you directly and include our contacts for the two systems' suppliers. For the benefit of the community could you post more information on how SIS 7.0 is managing to get locks on tables it has no access to please.

Comment: SIS uses cursors via libpq, and these are extremely slow unless a transaction is used. Unfortunately the metadata queries that we have to make touch lots of tables, eg those underlying a view, and, because the queries are inside a transaction, that causes the resource to be locked.

Comment: Is there something I can do with permissions that would prevent the locking of the tables - the user accounts don't appear to have access to the views and tables, but have I missed something obvious? Or is any user able to issue similar metadata queries on tables to which it does not have access?

Comment: For the benefit of GIS SE, the reason that the metadata queries used by SIS 'touch' even tables to which the logged in user does not have rights is that SIS does not know this with an initial "list the geometry columns" query. SIS uses the results of that query to fetch additional table/view metadata (permissions, pk column, etc). It is these secondary queries that (because they are inside a transaction) inadvertently lock the tables. It is simpler (and safer) for us to restart the transaction (which made no changes anyway) than to fiddle with the order or complexity of the metadata queries.

Comment: has supplied a replacement file Cadcorp.PostGIS.Dataset.dll which has alleviated the locking issue (except for the tables genuinely in use) for both our systems using embedded CadCorp SIS 7.0. Problem solved!